# How to save css style in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I use tinymce 5 to create newsletters and I need the code below inserted with "source code" to be saved and then reloaded by tinymce.
Now that code is removed.
How can I do?

```
<style type="text/css">
  .menu{
    font-size: 11px; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration:none
  } 
  a.menu:hover{ 
    font-size: 11px; color: #000000; text-decoration:none
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable the `fullpage` plugin you will see that the `<style>` content is moved to the `<head>` of the document as that is where the HTML spec says the `<style>` tag belongs to create valid HTML.

If you want to save that CSS and inject it later when the content is rendered you could certainly do that when the content is sent to the server to be stored.

Comment: If that solved the issue can you mark the question as resolved so others know the issue does not need further attention?  Welcome to Stack Overflow!